What are the differences between a vdi and vhdx file for VirtualBox, and can I safely delete any of them?
As I am using a ubuntu VirtualBox on a Windows 10 host I noticed two very large files:
A Ubuntu20.04.vdi file and a ext4.vhdx file in a weird named folder CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu20.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc.
Can I delete any of them? Or does the first one contain the operating system of the ubuntu system and the second one the virtual hard drive? Or anything I can do to reduce the sizes?

"Can I delete any of them?" - Only if you want to delete your VM.

The name of the file suggests you are actually looking at a WSL2 vhdx file instead. The other words the folder name is NOT associated with VirtualBox.

Since your question is about WSL2 not VirtualBox you should [edit] your question.  However, you will have to clarify your question, because it does not seem like you are tracking WSL2 is even installed if you are asking if you can delete the ext4.vdhx file. I can't nor can anyone else tell you, if you can delete a file on your system, you have to tell us if you are actively using WSL2.
